# moving from win7 to mac, eclipse missing Sun import

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've used eclipse for years in a windows environment. This week I got a brand new mac pro and I'm migrating everything from windows.  I copied my entire workspace from win7 box to the mac.  I've installed the latest eclpise (eclipse-SDK-4.2.2-macosx) and I've imported my projects... one of the classes in one of my projects can't seem to find two imports... I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what i need to add to the project to make it compile.

The two imports eclipse can't find:

```
import sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob;
import sun.print.Win32PrintJob;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you.

Comment: maybe win32 means windows ^^

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html). (on the side, I'm not sure why you'd expect Windows specific classes related to printers to work on Mac OS X)

Answer (score 6):

The `sun` packages are internal to a particular VM implementation and should not be used. Additionally, the class names are a good hint that they are Windows-specific on top of that and will definitely not be in an OSX JVM.

Comment: For further reading, check out [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)...

Answer (score 2):

Use java.awt.print instead. You can't use windows specific imports in osx.